# Wait for cURL response from a second Ratchet/ZeroMQ server

Tags: php, curl, zeromq, ratchet

I'm developing a solution where I send a POST request from the first server to the second server using cURL.

```php
function sendIcuCurlRequest($identity, $action, $payload){
    $url = '-- Removed --';

    $data = array(
        'identity' => $identity,
        'action' => $action,
        'payload' => $payload
    );
    $fields = http_build_query($data);

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

On the second server where the cURL request is picked up, ZeroMQ sends the data using `SOCKET_PUSH` to the WebSocket server (WebSocket server is on the second server).

```php
if(isset($_POST['identity'], $_POST['action'], $_POST['payload'])){
    $identity = $_POST['identity'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $payload = $_POST['payload'];

    $context = new ZMQContext();
    $socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'ICU push');
    $socket->connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:21002');
    $socket->send(json_encode(array('identity' => $identity, 'message' => formatRequest($action, $payload))));
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Invalid request";
    exit;
}
```

The WebSocket server then makes a RPC Call to the Client.

```php
public function onNewRequest($request){
    $requestData = json_decode($request, true);
    echo "Outgoing new request for Charge Point: ".var_export($request, true)."\n";

    // Check if is valid Station
    if(!array_key_exists($requestData['identity'], $this->stations)){
        echo "Identity {$requestData['identity']} not found.\n";
        return;
    }

    $station = $this->stations[$requestData['identity']];
    $res = $station->send(json_encode($requestData['message']));
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../logs/broadcast-'.date('Ymd').'.log', print_r($res, true)."\n\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

The Client after some thinking sends a CallResult to an `onCallResult` method with the response. (**Note:** I've modified Ratchet's WAMP core so it would be possible to receive CallResults from the Client)

```php
public function onCallResult(ConnectionInterface $conn, $id, array $params){
    $url = $conn->WebSocket->request->getUrl();

    echo "URL path -- ".$url."\n";
    echo "IP -- ".$conn->remoteAddress."\n";
    echo "Incoming call result (ID: $id)\n";
    echo "Payload -- ".var_export($params, true)."\n";
}
```

**Now to the fun part**
Now that I have the response from the Client, I would like to send that response back with cURL using the same connection the initial request came through.

I am thinking that with cURL alone I wouldn't be able to achieve this (I found that there is a new method like `curl_pause` but that is for 5.5 and up. Current server is running 5.4).

I did also find that ZeroMQ has a socalled `REQ` and `REP` but I can't quite figure out if that will serve the prupose on getting it work like this.

What would be the best for me to send a cURL response back to the initial request that came?

Comment: If you were to echo any information after processing received CURL request, that is what would be sent back. If you just abruptly `exit;` then empty data is sent back and connection is closed - meaning you can't use that connection any more to send data back.

Comment: Hmm, this is completely true that exiting the script after `$socket->send()` would end the connection. Then again when the `SOCKET_PUSH` goes to `onNewRequest` and that sends a RPC Call to the Client, then the `onNewRequest` method will finish without the CallResult from the Client since the CallResult is available in `onCallResult` method. The intriguing part of this is trying to have that CallResult from `onCallResult` method to be the response for cURL.

Comment: That means the calling code (one that initiates the CURL) would have to wait until you're done processing. However, here's something else to think about - when you initiate a CURL request give it some sort of an identifier (number, guid). Implement another socket at the CURL-initiating code that will uze `ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL`. Once you are done processing, you have request ID and you can use `ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH` to send the processed request. That way you have async request-reply. I don't know how feasible that is to implement at your current stage but it's something to think about.

Comment: If I understood correctly, then this approach would mean that the original method (on the first server that called `sendIcuCurlRequest`) won't be the one processing the cURL response. This of course is doable but the only setback would the lack of responding to user interaction. E.g if the user initiates the cURL request, then the user wouldn't know if the request was successful or not because the method that initiated the cURL wouldn't have any info on the response.

Comment: I don't have enough information, but you seem to be performing an async task execution. If I had your task, I'd approach this problem in a different way. Why don't you simply implement message exchanging between servers over ZeroMQ all together?